# Arduino as gateopener

Tags: arduino

I am new to codeing arduino.

I have a project which is about useing an arduino as a gate opener, but only when the temperature gets above 24 degrees. 
The problem is how do i get the arduino to send a signal to the relay to open, but only once?

I tried with if statements and trying under there to run with some while(1); but that seems to end the whole script. so that does not do what i want it to..

````
``` 
float temp;
int tempPin = A0;
int Relay1 = 13;
bool ronce = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(Relay1,OUTPUT);

}



void loop() {
  delay(500);

  temp = analogRead(tempPin);
  temp = temp * 0.48828125;
  Serial.print(temp);

if(temp>24){
   ronce == true;
   Serial.println(" Temp over 24 degree");

   if (ronce = true){
     Serial.println(" Ronce is true.");

 while(1){
 Serial.println("runOnce");
 digitalWrite(Relay1,HIGH);
 delay(500); 
 digitalWrite(Relay1,LOW); 
     }
   }
 }

else {
   ronce == false;
   Serial.println(" failure");
}

}
````

I want it to send a signal at 24 degrees to the relay to go on NC & ground and then turn off after 500 ms ish. 
then it should not turn on again until when it gets below 24 degrees again.

The output turns out between 20-37 degrees so the LM35 does as i want it to, it is just the code.

Comment: This is so far the diagram for this project is
https://gyazo.com/7de4e7837e9ca0484015822e9c49a24a

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a read function and then read it until it reaches above 24, then just turn on relay and wait again until the temp gets below 24.

```
int tempPin = A0;
int Relay1 = 13;

float read_temp()
{
    float sum = 0;
    float temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        sum += analogRead(tempPin);
        delayMicroseconds(100);
    }
    temp = sum / 500;
    temp = temp * 0.48828125;
    return temp;
}

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(Relay1, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    if (read_temp() > 24)
    {
        Serial.println("Temp over 24 degree");
        digitalWrite(Relay1, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(Relay1, LOW);
        // wait until temp reach below 23.5
        while (read_temp() > 23.5)
            ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it makes the relay go on and off 2 times when it reaches 24 degrees. is there someway to make this not happen?

Comment: When the temp reaches above 24 it would get stuck on `while`. So maybe it gets below 24 fast and goes up again. So I added an average to read temperature to fix it. I also reduce the `while` to 23.5 for the accuracy of LM35 but feel free to calibrate it.

Comment: I will test it as soon as i get a new arduino, the other one burned down, woops :P